# Thread issues happened whenever I tried to touch specific functions on my phone

Tags: swift, multithreading, sigabrt

My app does not crash on iOS 8.

But after updating it to 10 version on my phone, my app crashes when I try to use specific functions in the app.

But on simulator, it works well.

Whenever I installed the app on my phone, Thread # issues happened. And the number on # part always changes like below and I don't know why.

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:
    0x1c5eb440 <+0>:  mov    r12, sp
    0x1c5eb444 <+4>:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r8}
    0x1c5eb448 <+8>:  ldm    r12, {r4, r5, r6}
    0x1c5eb44c <+12>: mov    r12, #512
    0x1c5eb450 <+16>: orr    r12, r12, #9
    0x1c5eb454 <+20>: svc    #0x80
->  0x1c5eb458 <+24>: pop    {r4, r5, r6, r8}
    0x1c5eb45c <+28>: blo    0x1c5eb474                ; <+52>
    0x1c5eb460 <+32>: ldr    r12, [pc, #0x4]           ; <+44>
    0x1c5eb464 <+36>: ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
    0x1c5eb468 <+40>: b      0x1c5eb470                ; <+48>
    0x1c5eb46c <+44>: bne    0x1cea6364                ; CFStringROMTableHashData + 14212
    0x1c5eb470 <+48>: bx     r12
    0x1c5eb474 <+52>: bx     lr
```

what does the below error mean?

```
0x1c5eb458 <+24>: pop {r4, 45, r6, r8} = Thread #: signal SIGABRT
```

And some comments mentioned that I can solve this issues if I deleted "search path" on info.plist. So I tried to delete "Search Path" on info following them but it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved. 
The reason is microphone provisioning on info.plist.
Therefore, I added "privacy-microphone" menu on it. 
And it's solved.